# module 'qrcode' has no attribute 'make'

Tags: python, django, django-models, qr-code

While integrating python library qrcode==6.1 with django==3.1.2.
I have been trying to generate a qrcode which will contain the URL links for my other websites.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
import qrcode
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files import File
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Create your models here.

class Website(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qr_codes', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qrcode_img = qrcode.make(self.name)
        canvas = Image.new('RGB', (290,290), 'white')
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
        canvas.paste(qrcode_img)
        fname = f'qr_code_{self.name}.png'
        buffer = BytesIO()
        canvas.save(buffer,'PNG')
        self.qr_code.save(fname, File(buffer), save=False)
        canvas.close()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But It always display an error saying that module 'qrcode' doesnot contain any attribute named 'make()'. I want to know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure there are not any files named `qrcode.py` in the directory where `models.py` is located.

For more information check https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/issues/185

Answer (score 3):

was facing same even there is no file named 'qrcode.py' after multiple trying finally i come to find solution that there were multiple Qrcode installed in my project simply uninstall all of them and reinstall only one 'qrcode==6.1' the problem was solved...

Answer (score 1):

```
pip uninstall qrcode
pip install qrcode==6.1
```

Answer (score 1):

@Abhigyan Jaiswal's response is spot on and it did work for me.

I was trying to import `qrcode` as a module while my script was also named `qrcode.py`. I simply renamed `qrcode.py`  to `qrcodegen.py` and it worked.