# Python qrcode does not work inside docker

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

My django application generates a qrcode in the models everytime a new item is added through the form. It works perfectly fine when I run it using the python manage.py runserver command but when I dockerize the application, it shows the following error:

```
    qr_codes_img = qrcode.make(self.bag_asset_id)
    AttributeError: module 'qrcode' has no attribute 'make'
```

This is how I'm generating qr in the models.py:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    qr_codes_img = qrcode.make(self.bag_asset_id)
    canvas = Image.new('RGB', (290, 290), 'white')
    # canvas = Image.new('RGB', (qrcode_img.pixel_size, qrcode_img.pixel_size), 'white')
    canvas.paste(qr_codes_img)
    fname = f'qr_code-{self.bag_asset_id}.png'
    buffer = BytesIO() #inmemory storage
    canvas.save(buffer, 'PNG')
    self.bag_qr_code.save(fname, File(buffer), save=False) #if save not false infinite loop will enter
    canvas.close()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This only happens when I build and run the docker file, otherwise it works fine. I do not have any other file or function by the name 'qrcode' and the requirements.txt file is updated perfectly. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
    FROM python:3

    ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 
    libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils
    WORKDIR /app
    ADD . /app
    COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
    COPY . /app
```

Here's my requirements.txt

```
    asgiref==3.3.1
cffi==1.14.4
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
click-didyoumean==0.0.3
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.1.6
cloudpickle==1.2.2
colorama==0.4.1
comtypes==1.1.8
configparser==4.0.2
constantly==15.1.0
contextlib2==0.6.0
cryptography==3.3.1
cssselect==1.1.0
cycler==0.10.0
dask==2.5.2
decorator==4.4.0
defusedxml==0.6.0
diff-match-patch==20200713
Django==3.1.4
django-qrcode==0.3
django-rest-framework==0.1.0
django-session-timeout==0.0.4
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.5
djangorestframework==3.12.2
dnspython==2.0.0
docutils==0.15.2
entrypoints==0.3
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
filelock==3.0.12
flake8==3.7.9
fsspec==0.5.2
future==0.18.2
glob2==0.7
helpdev==0.7.1
html5lib==1.0.1
httplib2==0.18.1
hyperlink==20.0.1
imagesize==1.1.0
importlib-metadata==3.3.0
incremental==17.5.0
intervaltree==3.1.0
jdcal==1.4.1
jmespath==0.10.0
joblib==0.13.2
json5==0.8.5
jsonschema==3.0.2
keyring==18.0.0
kiwisolver==1.3.1
libarchive-c==2.8
locket==0.2.0
lxml==4.6.2
mccabe==0.6.1
mistune==0.8.4
mock==3.0.5
more-itertools==7.2.0
mpmath==1.1.0
msgpack==0.6.1
multipledispatch==0.6.0
mysql-connector-python==8.0.18
mysqlclient==2.0.2
numpy==1.19.4
numpydoc==0.9.1
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.0.1
olefile==0.46
packaging==19.2
pandas==1.1.5
pandocfilters==1.4.2
paramiko==2.7.2
parsel==1.6.0
parso==0.5.2
partd==1.0.0
path.py==12.0.1
pathlib2==2.3.5
pathtools==0.1.2
patsy==0.5.1
pep8==1.7.1
pexpect==4.7.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==8.1.0
Pillow-PIL==0.1.dev0
PillowImage==1.1.9
pkginfo==1.5.0.1
pluggy==0.13.0
ply==3.11
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==2.0.10
Protego==0.1.16
protobuf==3.6.0
psutil==5.8.0
ptyprocess==0.6.0
py==1.8.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
PyBundle==1.0.6
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pycparser==2.20
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
pydocstyle==5.1.1
pyflakes==2.1.1
PyHamcrest==2.0.2
pylint==2.4.2
PyMySQL==0.9.3
pyOpenSSL==20.0.1
pyparsing==2.4.2
pypng==0.0.20
PyQRCode==1.2.1
pyrsistent==0.15.4
pytest==5.2.1
pytest-arraydiff==0.3
pytest-astropy==0.5.0
pytest-astropy-header==0.1.2
pytest-doctestplus==0.4.0
pytest-openfiles==0.4.0
pytest-remotedata==0.3.2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.4
pyzmq==20.0.0
qrcode==6.1
qtconsole==5.0.1
queuelib==1.5.0
reportlab==3.5.59
requests==2.22.0
service-identity==18.1.0
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.9
sqlparse==0.4.1
sympy==1.4
tblib==1.4.0
testpath==0.4.2
toolz==0.10.0
xlrd==1.2.0
XlsxWriter==1.2.1
xlwt==1.3.0
```

My views.py function:

```
def qr_in_report(request, id):
name = " The QR code for "##insert id

obj = bags.objects.get(bag_asset_id=id)

context = {
    'name': name,
    'obj' : obj,
}

return render(request, 'mgx_qr/qr_report.html', context)
```

In my models.py, I have the ImageField 'bag_qr_code' for the 'bag' which is:

```
bag_qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qr_codes', blank=True)
```

So in my views, I'm only calling the bag object, and passing it on to my template. In my html file, I use this to display the qr code image.

```
<img src={{obj.bag_qr_code.url}}>
```

Please note, this error only shows up inside the docker, and not when i run using the runserver command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/64314692/11805525

Comment: where do you instantiate qrcode?

Comment: @MJafari that did not work, I don't have any other files or functions by that name.

Comment: @HaydenEastwood In the models. Should I add that code?

Comment: can you add your requirements.txt?

Comment: Please show the code - so we can see what's going on with your class instantiations

Comment: @Sirwill98 added it.

Comment: @HaydenEastwood edited it. I added the code.

Comment: You still haven't added how you instantiate qrcode - please include code that can, if possible, reproduce the error, or at least give us more context

Comment: @HaydenEastwood I added all the other codes, in the models and the views. The error only shows up when I build and run the application in docker. This does not show up when I use the python manage.py runserver command. From what I am understanding, inside the docker, it cannot generate the qrcode using the qrcode.make. Any insight on what might need to be added to the docker file would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you try run the docker command `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate --no-deps` in the project root directory.

Comment: @Arshi this is what I'm hoping to do but I can't see where you are importing qrcode in your script. It strikes me that either your Docker environment is different to your local machines (perhaps python version or something) or there's something in your environment variables themselves which is off. That's why I was wanting you to show imports and instantiations of all relevant qrcode-related parts of your code.

Comment: @Sirwill98 same issue. It runs, but when I try to add a new bag item, it shows the same attribute error.